# List all SVN repository URLs from a folder in recursive mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, svn

We are looking for a script that will traverse in recursive mode all subfolders and list all SVN repository URLs and the path where it was found.

It will be used on /home folder of a user.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work more or less independently of the svn version

```
find . -type d -exec svn info {} \; 2>/dev/null \
| awk '/^Repository Root/ { 
            if ($0 != repository) 
                print path " " $0; repository = $0
       }
       /^Path/ { path=$0 }'
```

Comment: This does a file parse, but this fails on svn1.7

Comment: @Pentium10 see the update to my Answer